# How to absolute positioning an icon inside input with text align and 50% width

Tags: css

I need a input horizontally centered and a icon inside. Something like this:

[image]

I have this code:

```css
.search { 
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:2em 0;
}

input[type="search"] { 
  text-indent: 2em;
  font-size:1.9em;
  padding:0.2em 0;
  width:50%;
}  
   

.fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 2em;
  color:orange;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="search">
     
  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Buscar" name="s" />

</div>
```

I checked that if I remove `left: 10px;` works fine in windows navigators but not in mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: The input needs to be 100% width, and the .search box needs to be of the width you want the input. By this way the icon will position perfectly respectly the relative box.

Comment: You're welcome. I upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See Snippet.**

```css
 .search { 
          position: relative;
          text-align:center;
          background-color:#ddd;
          padding:2em 0;
        }
        .search_inner{
          width:60%;
          position:relative;
          margin:auto;
          
          }
    
        input[type="search"] { 
          text-indent: 2em;
          font-size:1.9em;
          padding:0.2em 0;
          width:100%;
        }  
           
    
        .fa-search { 
          position: absolute;
          left: 10px;
          top:50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          font-size: 2em;
          color:orange;  
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="search">
   <div class="search_inner">    
     <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Buscar" name="s" />
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved thanks to @marcosperezgude comment

```css
.search { 
  
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:2em 0;
}

.search-inner {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
}

input[type="search"] { 
  text-indent: 2em;
  font-size:1.9em;
  padding:0.2em 0;  
}  
   

.fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 2em;
  color:orange;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="search">
  
  <div class="search-inner">
     
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Buscar" name="s" />
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.search { 
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:2em 0;
}
span {
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  }
input[type="search"] { 
  text-indent: 2em;
  font-size:1.9em;
  padding:0.2em 0;
  width:100%;
}  
   

.fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 2em;
  color:orange;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="search">
<span>     
  <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Buscar" name="s" />
</span>
</div>
```

add a containing span tag and set your search input to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research online including implementations from companies such as Tailwind (see [here](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/input-groups)), to position the icon to the left you do the following:

```
<div class="input-and-icon-wrapper">
    <input>
    <div class="icon">My Icon</div>
</div>
```

To position to the right, change `left` to `right` in `.icon`.

```
.input-and-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    /* width: 100%; */
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```